# react-native-vector-icons + mocha: Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, react-native, mocha.js, react-test-renderer, react-native-vector-icons

This is my Component. It runs without problems on emulator/phone:

```
// mycomponent.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
    // ...
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
               <Icon
                   name="check"
                   size={25}
                   color={'#62B300'}
               />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But when I run the unit test in this file (mocha --recursive test/**/*.js):

```
// mycomponent.spec.js
import chai from 'chai';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import mock from 'mock-require';
import 'react-native-mock-render/mock';
import {MyComponent} from '../app/components/MyComponent';

mock('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome', {});


describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
       const mycomponent = TestRenderer.create(<MyComponent>);

       return expect(mycomponent.root).to.exist;
    }
}
```

It throws:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up defau lt and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `MyComponent`.

It works if I use a `<View>` instead of the `<Icon>` but it should be mocked.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. To make this work, the mock needs to return a function returning `null` instead of an Object.

```
mock('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome', () => null);
```